# How much energy is required to create oxygen from carbon dioxide for one person per day?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

There is an [interesting question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73893) about the energy we gain from oxygen on StackExchange.

But I want to ask another way around: How much energy would we need to generate enough oxygen out of carbon dioxide for one person per day?

So let's imagine we want to live on the Moon. We enclose it in some kind of glass dome and would have to recreate all the oxygen that we breathe. And we have no trees or other organisms that would do this for us. How much energy would it require per day per person to generate enough oxygen?

**Update**

I would like to keep things simple, if possible:

- We have no trees or plants. So we need to to the chemical reaction "by hand".
- There is infinite amount of CO2 stored somewhere convenient in or near the dome. So we don't need to get CO2 from earth or generate it from something else.
- The Carbon we get out of CO2 can also be safely stored somewhere in or near the dome.

If your answer is more complicated, than this fine too. If the actual answer involves some kind of "cycle", where Carbon is reused somewhere else, I would still consider it. However I would love the answer to be as simple as possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because energy requirements depends on exact chemical reaction $CO_2 \to C + O_2$, hence it's more suitable for [chemistry.stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/915/how-can-carbon-dioxide-be-converted-into-carbon-and-oxygen).

Comment: By photosynthesis?

Comment: @my2cts As I understand it, OP forbids photosynthesis in the question by this requirement _we have no trees or other organisms that would do this for us_. So what's left is plain chemical reactions.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas, $\text{CO}_2\rightarrow\text{C}+\text{O}_2$ would be unsustainable even if it was practical. We can't eat pure carbon. (At least, we can't eat any allotrope that's been discovered to date.) What we'd need to sustain life is a reaction, maybe powered by sunlight, that converts $\text{CO}_2$ and water into carbohydrates.  If only there was some way...

Comment: @SolomonSlow That was just a short-cut (mnemonics) to what needs to be done. Full list of reactions is given in my mentioned chemistry.stackexchange site. I'm not a chemist, so I don't have even slightest clue what's sustainable or not in the world of chemics.  IMO, it's off-topic here.

Comment: The free energy difference between CO2 and C+O2 is straightforward, providing a minimum energy required.

Comment: Voting to reopen.

Comment: @JonCuster, If you say that reducing $\text{CO}_2$ to its pure elements requires less energy than the reactions I hinted at, then I'll just have to take your word for that. I only wanted to suggest that in paskster's hypothetical situation where, "we have no trees or other organisms that would [make oxygen] for us," making oxygen is only one part of our problem. Having oxygen to breathe is nice, but our bodies don't simply turn oxygen into energy. We need oxygen _and food_ to fuel our life processes.

Comment: If you've got some elemental fluorine lying around then [the reaction $\text{CO}_2 + \text{F}_2 \to \text{COF}_2 + \frac12 \text{O}_2$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022113906002983) actually liberates some energy.  Whether you want to have large quantities of elemental fluorine lying around your space station, or create large amounts of [toxic gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonyl_fluoride) in the process, is another question

Comment: Does the question include the transport of CO2 from Earth to the Moon? Is it allowed to use solar or should it be diesel transported from earth?